# python 2.7-Bool type not callable

Tags: python-2.7, types, boolean, callable

I have created the following:

```
import win32com.client as com

outlook = com.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
def ravi(str):
    newMail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
    newMail.Body = "I AM IN THE BODY\nSO AM I!!!"
    newMail.To = str
    #newMail.display()
    newMail.send()
    return

list = ["xyg@hpcl.in","gjk@gmail.com","lmn@yahoo.co.in" ]

for i in list:

ravi(i)
```

Though the emails are getting displayed, they are not being sent.

I am getting bool item not callable. Pls resolve.